# Import works, but does not import everything in the package?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I'm trying to use dispatch with a 3rd party website that has an OAuth authentication, but I'm having trouble importing things from dispatch. [Consumer api](http://databinder.net/dispatch-doc/#dispatch.oauth.Consumer) it is clearly there in the library, but for some reason it is not found. I'm using sbt to build the project, here is the dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.10.0"
```

And below is what running repl(sbt, console-quick) gives out. Trying to compile the project ends in similar *value not found* errors. The import doesn't fail, but Consumer isn't available. Other things from dispatch like Http are available just fine.

```
scala> import dispatch._  
import dispatch._      

scala> val x = Consumer("asdasdasd", "asdasdasdasad")  
console:10:
error: not found: value Consumer     
       val x = Consumer("asdasdasd", "asdasdasdasad")  
               ^  

scala> val y = new Http  
y: dispatch.Http = Http(com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient@1611cf2)
```

It seems someone else has had problems with this as well, but no answers..
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/NI3nZJjsrjo

The closes thing I've found is SomeConsumer in the `dispatch.oauth` package, but it isn't what I'm looking for. [Here](http://databinder.net/dispatch-doc/#dispatch.oauth.package) you can see Consumer and Token in the package, but

```
import dispatch.oauth._
```

Doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api is for 0.8 version.

If you read the documentation you use the reboot repository which is a complete rewrite of the dispatch using the async-http-client.

For an example usage you can see the [following code on gitub](https://github.com/n8han/herald/blob/master/src/main/scala/auth.scala) and the [following](https://github.com/n8han/herald/blob/master/src/main/scala/herald.scala)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this shortly!